# Exclude namespace declaration from result of XSL transform

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I'm generating an XML document in parts using various transforms. In particular, I'm generating a header which contains all of the namespace declarations and is then prepended to the document. However, the transform doesn't know about this and thus sticks on another declaration. This wouldn't usually be a problem, but millions of these things are generated and stored in a database, so having lots of redundant declarations floating about is rather annoying.

How do I turn off the generation of the namespace declarations? I've seen the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute, but the documentation for this states that declarations for used namespaces will be added anyway, which seems to render the option pointless.

Comment: You wrote _"I'm generating an XML document in parts using various transforms"_. Does this mean that you are using several stylesheets, ones imported, others included? If that's so, then you better declare all the namespaces in each `xsl:stylesheet` element in order to allow the namespace prefix fixup mechanism to do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of an XSLT transformation will always be well-formed (and namespace-well-formed) XML. If you want something that isn't, you're onto a loser.

I would question your design. It seems like a bad idea whose consequences you are starting to discover.

Comment: Did suspect that might be the answer. I think there are some reasons behind the design (I didn't come up with it) but it seems fair enough that it's not something that xslt will support.